# Reading Excel files with roo /rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, import-from-excel

I am using the rails gem called [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) to read and parse uploaded Excel and CSV files.

I understand that in roo, the way it reads an Excel file is `Excel.new("myfilename")`. I am facing issue because I have to read the file uploaded with form helper (upload helper), temp file. I am saving the temp file before reading it with roo/Excel.
Though I am uplaoding good excel files, I am getting

> the file is not an Excel/xlsx

error.

Is there a way to directly read from Uploaded IO?
Can you guys tell me what am I  doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually I have both Excel and xlsx..But I am using Excelx class to read xlsx files.The problem is with reading uploaded files.

Comment: Add to that I have .csv files and I am using ruby class CSV to read that..That works fine like CSV.parse(Uploded_io.read) ..But when I am trying to do the same with Excel/Excelex class ,it doesn't work.

Comment: do you see the files at the location you expect them to be? can you open/read them manually?  can you post your code?

Comment: Thanks rb512 ...I fixed it..the file was getting corrupted on upload..I was not saving it properly..

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing on a Windows box,  when you open files,  you have to add a 'b' (binary) to the file mode, i.e:

```
File.open("spreadsheet.xls","rb")
```

for read only, binary.

Not sure if that's your problem,  but I faced a similar problem and that was the solution.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with roo, but I have used http://rubygems.org/gems/parseexcel

```
workbook = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel.parse("#{Dir.getwd}/public/excel/foo.xls")
```